# Download Blobs from Azure with Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, azure, multiprocessing, azure-blob-storage, blobs

Is there anyone that knows how to use multiprocessing in python to download Blobs from Azure Storage?

The code below gives me this error: " TypeError: 'Blob' object is not iterable "

How to fix that?

Code:

```
def downloadBlobs(generator):
    for Blob in generator:
        path = 'temp/' + Blob.name.split('/')[-1]
        block_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,Blob.name,path)


if __name__  == '__main__':

    start = timeit.default_timer()

    generator = block_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME, prefix='trt2', num_results=1000)
    p = Pool()
    p.map(downloadBlobs, generator)

    final = timeit.default_timer() - start

    print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a case problem ??
Can you try with lower case :

```
for blob in generator:
    path = 'temp/' + blob.name.split('/')[-1]
    block_service.get_blob_to_path(CONTAINER_NAME,blob.name,path)
```

I guess Blob is a type so you can`t use it.

Comment: It was a good guess, but didn't work. I think the problem is in `map` function

Comment: @André could you expand? I'm trying the same thing.